# I want to share the hardwares between two systems which are connected on the same network

Tags: centos, resources, sharing

I want to share the hardwares between two systems which are connected on the same network.

I am having two desktops, one with 16GB RAM and other with 48GB RAM. Both are running CentOS minimal. I want to share the resources of both the system. So that I can get more resources on 48GB system (48+16GB RAM and processors as well). However, I won't be using 16GB system directly at all.

Thanks for any help

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something called [grid computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing) that allows you to share computer resources over a network. There are examples of [open sourced software](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) to facilitate this, it isn't something I have personally used so I can't advise you beyond that.

Depending on your requirements it maybe cheaper and easier just to rent some time on [Amazon's EC2 platform](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).

Comment: Thanks for some hint. I am planning to use Ovirt for creating multiple virtual systems. Is is possible to do so through Ovirt?

Comment: I just remembered reading about [Memcached](http://memcached.org/about) which might fit your needs better. Valve use it for the Steam platform.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't have a virtual grid. The usefulness is debatable as you aren't magicking up additional available computing power... Might be an interesting research project

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to use the memory attached to one system and have it treated as memory attached to another, separate system, this is not something you're going to be able to accomplish without some custom built (and amazingly expensive) hardware. (And even so, memory attached in such a way would be a lot slower.) About the closest mere mortals can come to this is getting a [dual processor motherboard](https://www.google.com/search?q=dual%20processor&tbm=isch).